# MySQL WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME()) gives wrong result

Tags: mysql

```
WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(1525212000))
```

gives result as 17 but it should be 18

Is it bug in MySQL or I am doing something wrong?

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.18

**Example Query**

[image]

**Timestamp to date online**

[image]

**Checking Date with online converer**

[image]

Comment: Your `FROM_UNIXTIME(1525212000)` giving `2018-05-01` and in online converter you are using `2018-05-02`

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided it would be best option to use WEEKOFYEAR function instead of WEEK function

> WEEKOFYEAR(date) Returns the calendar week of the date as a number in
>   the range from 1 to 53. WEEKOFYEAR() is a compatibility function that
>   is equivalent to WEEK(date,3).

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear

Answer (score 1):

The week can be in the range of 0-53, so you just need to add 1 to the result or better yet change the mode how weeks are counted with the second parameter to the week function.

`WEEK(date[,mode])`

Look at the official documention of the week function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

> If the mode argument is omitted, the value of the default_week_format
>   system variable is used